# Remove dynamic text from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a NSString with some text that i want to remove,this is the text that i want to remove from the NSString:

```
Textid="more-98989">
```

the number can change to another number.

Any way to do it ? Did i need Regex for this?

Comment: Which part of the text do you want to remove?

Comment: ideally regEx is the best way

Comment: What you want to filter... Textid should contain"more" or "98989"?

Comment: this is the text in the NSString and i want to remove it, i read in some places that i need to use Regex but i didn't found how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do it wit a regular expression, but you can also do without it just as easily. Locate the initial part of the string that you would like to remove, then search for the closing `">` **starting at the location of the `Textid="`**. This will give you the range of characters that needs to be removed.

```
NSString *myString = "Blah blah Textid="more-98989"> More stuff";
NSString *res = nil;
NSRange start = [myString rangeOfString:@"Textid=\""];
if (start.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange end = [myString rangeOfString:@"\">" withOptions:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(start.Location+1, myString.length-start.location-1)];
    if (end.location != NSNotFound) {
        res = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location-start.location+2) withString:@""];
    }
}
if (!res) {
    // Starting or ending tags were not found
    res = myString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

To remove this string from a different string, use:

```
NSString *stringToRemove = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"more-%@", dynamicNumber];
NSString *newString      = [bigString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToRemove 
                                                                withString:@""];
```

Comment: Or, if the fixed text is always the same length, one could simply use one of the `substring...` methods.

Comment: The '98989' is dynamic and can be another number

Comment: Well, you have to have that string somewhere, right?  How is it stored?  As another string?  number?  Just build the string the way that you need it.  I'll update to give an example.

Comment: I dont know how the string will get the number from the html

Comment: Okay, please update your question with exactly what your problem is then.  I'm guessing that it is something like "I have this number stored in a html file and I need to figure out how to extract it."??  Or, better yet, since it is different than "how do I remove text from a string" ask another question about extracting the number from the html.